# pagespeed convert image to webp but use not secure protocol (http)

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, https, pagespeed, webp

[Chrome Mixed Content Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNo5q.png)

My site was enabled nginx pagespeed module and all resources are loaded in https but webp url ( created by pagespeed ) is in http. I got a not-secure notice from Chrome brower. How to fix it?

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://interview.tw/c/QHkN' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://assets.interview.tw/images/xmask.jpg.pagespeed.ic.yjlu3AxgW4.webp'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Related image links solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable` fix this problem.

So put it on your pagespeed.conf file, clean the pagespeed cache (`sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush`) and restart Apache.

Good luck.